# How to connect wiimote and launch xbmc at the same time

Tags: xbmc

I would like to be able to launch xbmc when I connect my wiimote using xbmc-wiiremote.

For the moment, I have to launch a little script that start xbmc and xbmc-wiiremote and then push 1+2 of the wiimote but I would prefer to just push 1+2 of the wiimote when I want to start xbmc and the wiimote since I have no mouse and keyboard on this computer, just a Xbox 360 pad I use as mouse and for games (steam, etc.). I have spent a lot of time to find a solution but in vain.

The idea would be to have a script at startup.

Thank you for your help.